# How can I use com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer in a tv app?

Tags: android, pdf, android-tv, pdf-viewer

Getting Failed to resolve: com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1 when trying to add the package as an dependency.
Also tried to add jCentre as repository but that didn't work.

Suggestion of any other packages would be fine too.

project level gradle -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module level gradle -

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
}
```

settings.gradle -

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "####"
include ':app'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there, can you share your gradles, for modules and project?

Comment: instead of jCenter use mavenCentral()

Comment: Hi @TicherhazFreePalestine I have updated my question with both gradles

Comment: @Amartya can you share your settings.gradle  also?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine shared the settings.gradle

Comment: implement `jcenter()` below `mavenCentral()`. at the `dependencyResolutionManagement` . @Amartya

Answer (score 1):

**edit your `setting.gradle` to the following:**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "####"
include ':app'
```

**Include PDFView in your layout:**

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```